# Fixing rails 5 deprecation warning for matching routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

In my `routes.rb` file, I have the following

```
  resources :landings, only: [:index],
    path: '/golf' do
      collection do
        get 'break_70', path: 'how-to-break-70'
      end
  end
```

which generates a url

```
/golf/how-to-break-70
```

After upgrading to Rails 5, this generates the following deprecation message:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Specifying strings for both :path and the route path is deprecated. Change things like this:
  match "break_70", :path => "how-to-break-70"
to this:
  match "how-to-break-70", :as => "break_70", :action => "break_70"
```

If I try to follow these directions with

```
 resources :landings, only: [:index],
    match: '/golf' do
      collection do
        match: 'how-to-break-70', as: 'break_70', action: 'break_70'
      end
  end
```

then I get the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
        match: 'how-to-break-70', as: 'break_70', action: 'break_70'
```

How do I modify this route to avoid the deprecation warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
I update my answer to fix a little mistake so any reader can see a working code. Thanks @Obromios for the little fix.

In `resources` it should still be `path:`.
And in the route definition you have an extra ":" after `match`. Also you have to specify `via: [:get, :post]` if you `match`.
So the final version looks like:

```
resources :landings, only: [:index], path: '/golf' do
  collection do
    match 'how-to-break-70', as: 'break_70', action: 'break_70', via: [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

---

**Original Answer**

In `resources` it should still be `path:`.
And in the route definition you have an extra ":" after `match`
So the final version looks like:

```
resources :landings, only: [:index], path: '/golf' do
  collection do
    match 'how-to-break-70', as: 'break_70', action: 'break_70'
  end
end
```

Not tested, but should work.

Comment: This generated an exception: You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. However, if I change 'match' to get it works and there is no deprecation warning. I have edited your post accordingly.  I have accepted and upvoted  your answer. If you think a question is useful you should upvote it.