# Rails 5.1 "Ambigous route definition. Both :path and the route path where specified as strings. (ArgumentError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

On Rails 5.0.5, the following route definition works

```
get 'terms_of_use', to: 'pages#terms_of_use', path: "terms-of-use"
```

On 5.1.3, I get the following error when starting the Rails server

```
/home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionpack-5.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1852:in `block in map_match': Ambigous route definition. Both :path and the route path where specified as strings. (ArgumentError)
```

Am I using `path:` incorrectly for Rails 5.1.3 or is this a Rails bug?

The misspelling of "Ambigous" and the incorrect usage of "where" in the error message doesn't give me a whole lot of confidence in the correctness of Rails on this one...

Comment: How did you update to Rails 5.1.3? It seems that the incorrectly spelled error message is pre-5.1.3, as that typo has been addressed by https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9f7c9ee44d9d433a089515e8d4b804a312693c8b

Comment: I went directly from Rails 5.0.5 to Rails 5.1.3.  I looked at the differences reported by railsdiff.org between the two versions. I manually made the file changes, to address the differences, to bring the app up to Rails 5.1.3. In the Gemfile, I changed the Rails version to 5.1.3.  I deleted the Gemfile and did a full bundle.  Rails 5.1.3 is definitely in the Gemfile.lock.

Comment: It looks like they only merged that commit into master.  Nothings been changed in the 5.1 branch.

Comment: Ah, you're right about that. It seems that passing `:path` and the route path as strings while declaring a route has been fully deprecated in the newer Rails version - see https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9185b68cc652a113a85e29c8d6f7655f360cbedb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the following:

`get :terms_of_use, to: 'pages#terms_of_use', path: 'terms-of-use'`

or

`get 'terms-of-use', to: :terms_of_use, controller: 'pages'`

Comment: The following post on SO may also be interesting for more complex routing cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097422/fixing-rails-5-deprecation-warning-for-matching-routes

Comment: The latter worked.  I ended up using `get 'terms-of-use', to: 'pages#terms_of_use'"`